# How to use DateTime in Expressions for LINQ to Entities?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, expression

I know how to build an Expression tree to query Entity Framework, eg.

```
        string propertyName = "Name";
        string keyword = "Methanol";

        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Chemical), "x");

        MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
        ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(keyword, typeof(string));
        BinaryExpression body = Expression.Equal(me, constant);
        var isEqualExpressionTree = Expression.Lambda<Func<Chemical, bool>>(body, new[] { parameter });
        Expression<Func<Chemical, bool>> funcExpression = (Expression<Func<Chemical, bool>>)isEqualExpressionTree;

        using (var mLEntities = new myLab02Entities1())
        {
            var cl = mLEntities.Chemicals.AsQueryable().Where(funcExpression).ToList();       
            return cl;

        }
```

"Name" is a field in the SQL-database and it should be checked for "Methanol". The Lambda that is build inside is:
    {x => (x.Name == "Methanol")}. Now I want to test DateTime fields of the database, but only with the Date-portion. So my Lambda would be

{x => DbFunctions.TruncaateTime(x.EntryDate) == DbFunction.TruncateTime(testDate)}. This works as is, but how can I convert this to an Expression?
 Thanks, Hucky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 string propertyName = "EntryDate";
 DateTime testDate = DateTime.Now;            

 ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Chemical), "x");
 MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
 var ce = Expression.Convert(me, typeof(DateTime?));
 MethodCallExpression mc = Expression.Call(null, typeof(DbFunctions).GetMethod("TruncateTime", new Type[] { typeof(DateTime?) }), ce);
 ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(testDate, typeof(DateTime?));
 BinaryExpression body = Expression.Equal(mc, constant);
 var isEqualExpressionTree = Expression.Lambda<Func<Chemical, bool>>(body, new[] { parameter });
 Expression<Func<Chemical, bool>> funcExpression = (Expression<Func<Chemical, bool>>)isEqualExpressionTree;
```

Comment: Hi Akos, thanks for your reply. I get an error for Typeof(DbFunctions): Type or Namespace "DbFunctions" not found.  I cannot add "using System.Data.Entity" to the recent Project, although this is possible in other Projects in this solution. I try to find out what is going on here.

Comment: It is installed, but I try to  install it again.

Comment: Hi Akos, I transfered your code into a Project where I had the System.Data.Entity namespace included, And it shows no errors. Unfortunately when I run the code in Debugger, I get an exception for the line with MethodCallExpression, but I cannot see the exception message. I will try to fix it tomorrow. Hucky

Comment: Any luck with this? I can help you track down any bugs if you need help. For me this works, so I'm most curious about what's wrong on your side.

Comment: Hi Akos, I really appreciate that you try to help me. When run your Code, the line with the MethodCallExpression throws an exception:    System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Comment: The Code above runs in my DataAcessLayer, which is called from the UI by a WCF Service -> Business Logic -> DAL. I am just trying to get more Information about the exception. Hucky

Comment: Just do what the exception says: find the config file of the WCF service, and there should be an includeExceptionDetailsInFaults tag with a value set to false. Set it to true and run it again, you should see the exception on the client as well.

Comment: I get the message in german, I think it is something like: An expression of type "System.DateTime" cannot be used for parameters of type "System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]" of the System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime] TruncateTime(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])-Method. In the database EntryDate is not nullable, and in the original query without Expression this worked. MethodCallExpression mc = Expression.Call(null, typeof(DbFunctions).GetMethod("TruncateTime", new Type[] { typeof(DateTime?) }), me) also throws the exception. Hucky

Comment: OK, I see. I've edited the my answer, to create the expression for non-nullable methods. Not sure, but this might work.

Comment: I did some testing with a dummy data model, and found a case where the running the query throws an exception because of the Expression.New(). I suggest you use Expression.Convert() instead; see my edited answer. Hopefully this will be good for all situation.